# Import data from excel file as numpy array

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .csv file with 250 variables (integer and float) with given column names. First column is serial number and last column is 'label'
I am using this code from github to import it as numpy array:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
train_data = genfromtxt("file.csv", delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=float)
```

The output is:

```
[ ( 0.,  25.20824887, -16.745.......,) (( 1., -86.93144987,   0.42822719, ...)]
```

There is no comma separation between rows.

How can I get the output into proper numpy array format excluding first column and storing last column into different 'Y' variable.

I am using this code:

```
  np.reshape(train_data,(train_data.size, len(train_data[0])))
```

It's giving the error as:

```
cannot reshape array of size 7200 into shape (7200,252)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try first importing it as a pandas dataframe using the .read_csv() method. Then use the DataFrame.as_matrix() method on the dataframe generated by .read_csv() to convert the actual values to a numpy array. Unfortunately the .as_matrix() method will not retain each columns dtype if they are different so use this with care only if you know casting won't be an issue. Read this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

edit:
 "The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen.....e.g. If the dtypes are float16 and float32, dtype will be upcast to float32...By numpy.find_common_type convention, mixing int64 and uint64 will result in a float64 dtype."

So in your case it will most likely cast all values to float64.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.